# My mern auth code doesn't work when I try to register I tested it with Postman and it always shows Error signing up

Tags: mongodb, express, authentication, mern

My mern auth code dosen't work when I try to register. I tested it with postman and it always shows Error signing up. `getAllUsers` works fine, but `createUser` doesn't work at all. It always shows me "Error signing up" in the Postman terminal

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../models/user.model')
const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY
module.exports.createUser = async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const { email, username, password } = req.body
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
        const newUser = new User({ email, username, password: hashedPassword })
        await newUser.save()
        res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created successfully' })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error signing up' })
    }
}
module.exports.getAllUsers = async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const users = await User.find()
        res.status(201).json(users)
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Unable to get users' })
    }
}
module.exports.loginUser = async (req,res)=>{
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body
        const user = await User.findOne({ username })
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials'})
        }
        const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if(!isPasswordValid) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid credentials' })
        }
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '1hr' })
        res.json({ message: 'Login successful' })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error logging in' })
    }
}
```